# Count and index consecutive rows that satisfy a condition

Tags: r

Trying to find how to cleanly count in R the number of **consecutive** vector rows such that a vector entry `<= c_1` for the first time until vector entry `>= c_2` for the first time, where `c_1 < c_2`. I also want to get an index where these entries started (or stopped) satisfying the stated condition.

For example

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,4,3,NA, 2,1)
```

If `c_1=2` and `c_2=3`, then, 3 consecutive entries (the first 2) satisfied the condition, the next four entries do not, a NA is discarded, and the last two entries satisfied the condition as well. Therefore my count of consecutive entries satisfying the condition are 3,2 and the indexes where consecutive entries started are 1 and 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a, perhaps not most efficient, solution:

```
i<-1;dur_d<-NULL;index_w<-NULL
while(i < length(v1)){
  k<-0
  if(v1[i]<= 2 & is.na(v1[i])==F){
    count<-1;k<-1;index_w<-rbind(index_w,i)
    while(v1[i+k]<3 & is.na(v1[i+k])==F){
        count<-count+1;k=k+1}
  dur_d<-rbind(dur_d,count);
  }
  i<-i+k+1
}
```